# How to retain data in a MAUI Application following the MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, data-binding, maui

I have set up a new MAUI application and started to structure the application for the MVVM Pattern with a folder for Views, Viewmodels and Models. The root folder only containing the App.xaml and AppShell.xaml and the MauiProgram.cs.

I have setup the navigation in the shell and am able to navigate to the different views.
One of my views is basically a list with a hovering button in the bottom right corner. When i click this button I show a Community Toolkit popup containing a textinput and a button.
When I press this button I want to add an Item to a list.

So I set a View "DailyPage" and a Viewmodel "DailyViewModel".
The Viewmodel code looks like this:

```
public class DailyViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        ObservableRangeCollection<ExampleModel> _DailyList { get; set;}
        public ObservableRangeCollection<ExampleModel> DailyList
        {
            get => _DailyList;
            set
            {
                _DailyList = value;
            }
        }
        public AsyncCommand RefreshCommand { get; }

        public DailyViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Daily Page";
            AddObjectCommand= new MvvmHelpers.Commands.Command(AddObject);
            RefreshCommand = new AsyncCommand(Refresh);
            _DailyList = new ObservableRangeCollection<ExampleModel>
            {
                new ExampleModel{ Name = "Test1" },
                new ExampleModel{ Name = "Test2" },
                new ExampleModel{ Name = "Test3" },
                new ExampleModel{ Name = "Test4" }
            };
        }
        string addName = "-";
        public string AddName
        {
            get => addName;
            set => SetProperty(ref addName, value);
        }

        public ICommand AddObjectCommand { get; }

        void AddObject()
        {
            ExampleModel ex = new ExampleModel() { Name = AddName };
            _DailyList.Add(ex);
        }
```

The DailyPage view looks like this:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
        <ListView BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional,HeightProportional,WidthProportional"
                  Margin="10"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DailyList,Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ExampleModel">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="5"
                              HorizontalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   FontSize="Large"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   Grid.Column="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                       
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button Text="+"
                FontSize="Large"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,100,100"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                Margin="10"
                Clicked="onAddEntryClicked"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

The Entry popup where the data shall be entered looks like this:

```
<toolkit:Popup.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:DailyViewModel/>
</toolkit:Popup.BindingContext>
    
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="Name"
               FontSize="Large"/>
        <Entry Text="{Binding AddName}"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding AddObjectCommand}"
                Text="Add"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

I also have referenced to the DailyViewModel in both the DailyPage and the AddEntryPopup like this:

```
x:DataType="viewmodels:DailyViewModel"
```

so the Compiled DataBinding and the Intellisense works as intended.

Up until the adding of data via the command everything works as expected. I navigate to the view, I see a list with the example data I added to the list in the viewmodel.
When I press the "+" Button the popup shows and lets me enter the data.
When the "Add" button is pressed even the "AddObjectCommand" is executed and when I debug it and look in the watchlist the object is successfully added.

I was expecting, that when I add an Object to the ObservableRangeCollection, this object will later be found in my List as I set up a databinding to that observableRangeCollection. But I found that everytime I execute the AddObjectCommand, the Collection only contains of the items that I set up as demo data (Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4) but not the ones I already added.

Why is this data lost even though the actual view is not changed?
How would you store data so it isnt lost when you change views?

Initially I thought the problem will occur when I start switching views, as data is not stored globally in an MVVM pattern, but it seems that data is also not retained when working with a viewmodel.
This is my first time really trying to use the MVVM patterns. I have read a lot about it and I think I got the structure and the goal, but I seem to fail on the execution.
Edit: DailyPage Codebehind

```
public partial class DailyPage : ContentPage
{
    public DailyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }
    async void onAddEntryClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var entryPopup = new AddEntryPopup();
        await this.ShowPopupAsync(entryPopup);
    }
}
```

Comment: your popup is creating a **new instance** of the VM, not sharing the same instance with the other page

Comment: Use the debugger, set a breakpoint at the constructor of the DailyViewModel and now you should see why

Comment: Please show the code behind. That's where you should set the `BindingContext` in your particular scenario. Also, please show how you instantiate the popup. Currently, you're creating a new instance of the ViewModel everytime, because of this line: `<viewmodels:DailyViewModel/>`. You should reuse the ViewModel instead of instantiating it with every new popup.

Comment: @ewerspej For now i went with Jessie Zhangs solution, but initially I also wanted to use the DailyViewModel for the popup, as it logically belongs to the DailyPage anyways. How would you reuse or reference to an instance of a viewmodel when calling a popup?

Comment: @NicoSz It depends. With Shell, I would use MAUI's built-in dependency injection capabilities and make the ViewModel a singleton instance in the IoC/services container. That way, all Views that share that particular ViewModel will work on the same instance and have access to the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even the two pages (`DailyPage` and `AddEntryPopup`) share the same Viewmodel (`DailyViewModel.cs`),two different new instances of the `DailyViewModel.cs` will be created. So the two pages cannot share the same value for `_DailyList`   and variable `public string AddName`.

For this problem, you can use two different VMs for the two pages and pass the new added data between the pages(for example, you can use [MessageCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter?view=net-maui-7.0) to pass data).

I have created a demo and achieved this function.
You can refer to the following code:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodels:DailyViewModel></viewmodels:DailyViewModel>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

 <VerticalStackLayout
        Spacing="25"
        Padding="30,0"
        VerticalOptions="Start">
     
            <ListView BackgroundColor="Transparent"
              Margin="10"
              ItemsSource="{Binding DailyList,Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:ExampleModel">
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Padding="5"
                          HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                               FontSize="Large"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Grid.Column="1"/>
                            </Grid>

                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <Button Text="+"
            FontSize="Large"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,100,100"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
            Margin="10"
            Clicked="onAddEntryClicked"/>
 </VerticalStackLayout>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{
      public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

    private async  void onAddEntryClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var addPage = new AddItemPage();
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(addPage);
    }
}
```

**DailyViewModel.cs**

```
public class DailyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    ObservableCollection<ExampleModel> _DailyList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ExampleModel> DailyList
    {
        get => _DailyList;
        set
        {
            _DailyList = value;
        }
    }
    public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; }

    public DailyViewModel()
    {
        _DailyList = new ObservableCollection<ExampleModel>
        {
            new ExampleModel{ Name = "Test1" },
            new ExampleModel{ Name = "Test2" },
            new ExampleModel{ Name = "Test3" },
            new ExampleModel{ Name = "Test4" }
        };


        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<AddItemViewModel, ExampleModel>(this, "NewItem", (obj, item) =>
        {
            var newItem = item as ExampleModel;

            _DailyList.Add(newItem);
        });


    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

**AddItemPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiAddItemToListApp.Views.AddItemPage"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiAddItemToListApp.ViewModels"
             Title="AddItemPage">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="Name"
               FontSize="Large"/>
        <Entry Text="{Binding AddName}"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding AddObjectCommand}"
                Text="Add"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**AddItemPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class AddItemPage : ContentPage 
{
      public AddItemPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BindingContext =  new AddItemViewModel(Navigation);
      }
}
```

**AddItemViewModel.cs**

```
public class AddItemViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public INavigation Navigation { get; set; }

    public AddItemViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        AddObjectCommand = new Command(addItem);
        this.Navigation = navigation;
    }

    string addName = "";
    public string AddName
    {
        get => addName;
        set => SetProperty(ref addName, value);
    }

    public ICommand AddObjectCommand { get; }

    private async void addItem()
    {
        ExampleModel newItem = new ExampleModel();
        newItem.Name = AddName;
        //send message
        MessagingCenter.Send(this, "NewItem", newItem);

        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: I think it should be possible to just reuse the ViewModel, but that requires some additional information from the OP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried implementing your solution but VS advised me to use WeakReferenceMessenger Instead of MessagingCenter as its obsolete. After changing over to that the application works as intended!